# Error Returning A Dictionary From A Function

Tags: vb.net

I have created a function to group data..

> ```
> Private Function GroupData(ByVal validData As DataSet) As Dictionary(Of [String], List(Of DataRow))()
>
>         Dim serviceGroupDataset As DataSet = validData.Clone
>
>         Dim grouped As New Dictionary(Of [String], List(Of DataRow))()
>         Dim groupedRows As List(Of DataRow) = New List(Of DataRow)
>
>         For Each r As DataRow In validData.Tables("Detail").[Select]()
>
>             Dim key As [String] = r(AuthorizatonConstants.VA_Authorization_ID).ToString().Split("-"c)(0)
>
>             If Not grouped.TryGetValue(key, groupedRows) Then
>                 groupedRows = New List(Of DataRow)()
>                 grouped(key) = groupedRows
>             End If
>
>             groupedRows.Add(r)
>         Next
>
> //COMPILE ERROR
>         Return grouped
>     End Function
> ```

I am getting a compile error when trying to return the dictionary..

```
Value of type 'System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary(Of String, System.Collections.Generic.List(Of System.Data.DataRow))' cannot be converted to '1-dimensional array of System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary(Of String, System.Collections.Generic.List(Of System.Data.DataRow))'.
```

How can I return the grouped dictionary from the function?

Comment: What use is () (the closing brackets) in `Dictionary(Of [String], List(Of DataRow))()`? Can you remove those from the code wherever it is used?

Comment: Could those () be array brackets?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your method signature is returning a `Dictionary`-array(because of the following `()`), i assume you want to return a single dictionary.

You can use this `Linq-To-DataTable` approach which is more comprehensible:

```
Private Function GroupData(ByVal validData As DataSet) As Dictionary(Of String, List(Of DataRow))   
    Dim groups = From row In validData.Tables("Detail")
                  Let id = row.Field(Of String)(AuthorizatonConstants.VA_Authorization_ID).Split("-"c)(0)
                  Group row By id Into RowGroup = Group
    Dim grouped As Dictionary(Of String, List(Of DataRow)) = groups.
        ToDictionary(Function(grp) grp.id, Function(grp) grp.RowGroup.ToList())    
    Return grouped
End Function
```